# How to get the name of the first worksheet linqtoexcel?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have problem in getting the first worksheet linqtoexcel.

My code:

```
 var vitem = from oSelectedSheet in vFile.Worksheet<users>(1) select oSelectedSheet;
```

In case sheet default (sheet1) in file does not exist, this code doesn't give what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works,

```
     var vFile = new LinqToExcel.ExcelQueryFactory(sTargetFileName);
     var worksheetNames = vFile.GetWorksheetNames();

     worksheetNames.First()//got
```

Comment: This doesn't give the first worksheet in the spreadsheet. It only gives the first worksheet alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

To get the first worksheet by position, you need to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.  Once you have the name, then you can use LinqToExcel to get the contents of the worksheet by name.

```
string firstWorksheetName = null;
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(path, false))
{
    var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
    firstWorksheetName = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook
        .Descendants<Sheet>()
        .OrderBy(d => d.SheetId.Value)
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?.Name.ToString();
}

var results = new List<MappedType>();

using (var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(path))
{
   ... // set up database engine, access and any mapping

   results = excel.WorksheetRange<MappedType>("A2", "J16384", firstWorksheetName).ToList();
}
if (results.Count() != 0) {
   ... // Do stuff
}
```